# android opengl GLUtil.texImage2d

Tags: android, opengl-es

i hava a bmp size =512*512,and now i want to use it to render a surface
since the surface is not plain, i cut the surface into small piece of rectangle(num = rowMax * colMax), the code like this:

```
draw(GL10 gl)
{  
  int[] textures = new int[];
  gl.glBindTexture(...);
  gl.glTxtParameterf(...);

 for(int row =0; row< maxRow; row++)
 {
   for(int col=0; col<maxCol; col++
  { 
     GLUtil.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D , bitmap,0 );// bitmap is the 512*512 bmp
    //generate 4 point coordinate
    ...

    //generate texture uv coordinate 
    ...
    //draw it
   gl.glDrawArray(...);    
    }  
  }
```

}
it works fine.

but when i take the statement:
GLUtil.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D , bitmap,0 );
out of the loop,(since i think this may take a lot of time )
it doesn't work,i don't know w

}

Comment: There is no `texImage2D'3` in [GLUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLUtils.html).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't understand the way your program works, but from what i understand you have num different textures that you need to draw.

Were you to take the texImage2D out of the loop, you would load just one texture instead of num texture so obviously that wouldn't work.

Another thing to know about open gl, is that you don't need to call GLUtil.texImage2D every time you draw, but only every time the texture changes.

Once you call texImage2D, the current state of bitmap is saved to the texture memory of the GL context, under the texture name you previously called `glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, /*texture name here*/)` with, so next time you need to draw the texture, you only need to call glBindTexture with the name of the texture, and that's it, no costly operations needed.

What you should do is make it so that each texture's name (a unique integer to represent the texture) is it's position (=(row * maxCol) + col) + 1 (so that you don't have a texture named 0 (reserved texture name).

Also, you should create an array of booleans the size of num called mDirty, so that each cell is true when the texture corresponding to the position of the cell has changed and needs to be reloaded.

This way, you can in the loop just check whether `mDirty[(row * maxCol) + col] == true`, and if it is true, then call texImage2D, and set mDirty[(row * maxCol) + col] to false to indicate that the texture is updated in the gl memory.

Comment: actually, there is only one texture, each time i use a part of them,for example use the upper-left part 64*64 pixel. every time the GLUtils.glTexImage2D load the same bitmap to texture ,and that' costly.is there some way only load only once?

Comment: oh, in this case, move the glTex out of the loop, and place a  glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, /*texture name here*/) command before it.